# Proper way to use join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have four tables in my database like as follow

1. Table `Transactions` to differentiate purchase and sale transactions
2. Table `Products` to maintain product details
3. Table `Stocks` to maintain products quantity
4. Table `BillDetails` to maintain `Purchase` and `Sales`

[image]

I did try to purchase and sold operation using interface and it works correctly
but I am having problem with retrieving data from these three tables using SQL Server join to show me (From which product how much I have purchased and how much I sold).

The code I tried is as follows.

```
select 
    pro_ID
    , sum(case when trn_type = 'PRCH' then stk_quantity else 0 end) as stock
    , sum(case when trn_type = 'PRCH' then bdt_quantity else 0 end) as purchase
    , sum(case when trn_type = 'SALE' then bdt_quantity else 0 end) as Sale
    , sum(case when trn_type = 'PRCH' then bdt_quantity else 0 end)-(sum(case 
        when trn_type = 'PRCH' then bdt_quantity else 0 end)- sum(case when 
        trn_type = 'SALE' then bdt_quantity else 0 end)) as diff
from 
    stocks
join 
    Products on Products.pro_ID = Stocks.stk_Product
right outer join 
    BillDetails on Products.pro_iD = BillDetails.bdt_Product
join 
    Transactions on BillDetails.bdt_trnRef = Transactions.trn_Reference
where 
    pro_ID = '6260100600362'
group by 
    pro_ID 
order by 
    pro_ID asc
```

As I sold only one of the mentioned products but my query gives me wrong result in sold and purchase like following in screen shot.

[image]

Based on table information the correct information or result should be like following.

1. Stocks = 123
2. Purchase = 124
3. Sales = 1
4. Difference = 1

Comment: Tip: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Comment: Given that the incorrect numbers are exactly double the desired values, you're probably joining on criteria which are not precise enough (or duplicates just exist in the data to begin with ). Also, Why not add trn_type to the group by clause instead of the case statement

Comment: I tried but same result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using stock table as your base table. And you have two entries for the same proID/stk_product in your base table. Then whenever you doing the join with the condition on this id, you will have two entries afterwards with the same value on your join tables. So after you do the sum, you will double your value.

I would suggest you use product as your base table and then do the joins.

You can try this:

```
with stocks as (
    select 
        Stk_trnref
        , stk_Product
        , sum(stk_quantity) stk_quantity
    group by Stk_trnref, stk_Product
),

select 
  stk_Product
  , sum(case when trn_type = 'PRCH' then stk_quantity else 0 end) as stock
  , sum(case when trn_type = 'PRCH' then bdt_quantity else 0 end) as purchase
  , sum(case when trn_type = 'SALE' then bdt_quantity else 0 end) as Sale
  , sum(case when trn_type = 'PRCH' then bdt_quantity else 0 end)-(sum(case 
    when trn_type = 'PRCH' then bdt_quantity else 0 end)- sum(case when 
    trn_type = 'SALE' then bdt_quantity else 0 end)) as diff
from Products
left join stocks on Products.pro_ID = Stocks.stk_Product
left join BillDetails on Products.pro_iD = BillDetails.bdt_Product
left join Transactions on BillDetails.bdt_trnRef = Transactions.trn_Reference
where pro_ID = '6260100600362'
group by pro_ID order by pro_ID asc
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I try your work and suggestion but unfortunately it has the same result. and let me tell you that I have change my base table to other tables but not working.

Comment: Seems like still the stock table issue. You can first aggregate and get sum of stock table and then do the joins

Comment: can you give me an example in SQL statements if you don't mind